# HttpEndRequest error handling and retry

Tags: file-upload, error-handling, wininet

I upload a file to the server with WinInet using `HttpSendRequestEx -> InternetWriteFile -> HttpEndRequest` approach.

If some error happens (e.g. 401) and I can fix/retry it with the same request handle, should I repeat `HttpEndRequest` only or both `InternetWriteFile -> HttpEndRequest`?

Comment: You can't mix WinINet and WinHTTP in the same code. You can put them in different c++ files. Stick with WinINet if you don't need server implementation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpsendrequestexa

After the call to HttpSendRequestEx, send the remaining data by calling InternetWriteFile. Finally, follow up with a call to HttpEndRequest.